# Computation of the Laplace transform of the Gaussian heat kernel

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, heat-equation, gaussian-integral, gaussian

Currently I'm interested in the Laplace transform of the Gaussian heat kernel
$$
k_t(x):=\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^\frac{d}{2}}e ^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}.
$$
Using the Laplace transform
$$
 G_\lambda(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}p_t(x)\mathrm{d}t=\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^\frac{d}{2}}e^{-\frac{|x|^2}{4t}}\mathrm{d}t
$$
Via square addition on the exponent, I ended up trying to compute
$$
G_\lambda(x)=(4\pi)^{-\frac{d}{2}}e^{\sqrt{\lambda}|x|}\int_0^\infty t^{-\frac{d}{2}}e^{-\bigl(\frac{|x|}{\sqrt{4t}}+\sqrt{\lambda t}\bigr)^2}\mathrm{d}t.
$$
From there I'm not able to go any further, since I don't know how to get rid of the term $t^{-\frac{d}{2}}$. I actually looked up in the already discussed threads on the Laplace transform of the Gaussian but I'm not able to follow the final computation.
I would be deeply thankful for any hints how to go on from the last expression.
Best regards, Philipp

Comment: Do you actually want the temporal transform rather than the spatial one?

Answer (score 1):

What you are calculating is known as the resolvent which is the fundamental solution of the equation
$$
\Delta f-\lambda f=-\rho\,
$$
for the the whole domain $\mathbb R^d.$
In [1] it is shown that, for $d\ge 2,$
\begin{align}\boxed{\quad
\int_0^\infty e^{-\lambda t}\frac{1}{(4\pi t)^{d/2}}\exp\Big(-\frac{|x-y|^2}{4t}\Big)\,dt=\frac{\lambda^\frac{d-2}{4} K_\frac{d-2}{2}\Big(\sqrt{\lambda}\,|x-y|\Big)}{2\pi^{d/2}\Big(2\,|x-y|\Big)^\frac{d-2}{2}}\,,\quad}
\end{align}
where $K_\nu(z)$ is the Bessel function of the third kind.

[1] R.L. Schilling, L. Partzsch, *Brownian Motion. An Introduction to Stochastic Processes.* de Gruyter Graduate, Berlin 2012.

Comment: Ooh great thanks! That helped me a lot. I was quite able to follow the proof on the case $d=1$. I'm trying to reconstruct the case $d \geq 2$ the next few days.